# Google App Engine: Blank page after POST request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

When I click on the "Add" button in my web application, this address shows up:

localhost:8080/add

but with a blank page.

main.py:

```
class Add(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print("Test")
        ...
        return self.redirect("/admin_page")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([...
                                ('/add', Add),
                                ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

In the Log Console, it doesn't reach the `print("Test")` line. The log shows:

```
INFO     2013-09-07 13:14:42,423 server.py:528] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And stuck there, it doesn't continue to run.

What might be the issue and how to solve it?

---

***Edit:***

The variable `result` recieves the right value, but the function doesn't perform the redirect:

```
class Add(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ...
        logging.debug("result in main.py = %s", result)
        if result is 0:
            return self.redirect("/admin_page")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([...
                               ('/add', Add),
                               ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Log Console output:

```
DEBUG    2013-09-07 12:36:07,167 main.py:362] result in main.py = 0
```

And it shows the blank page at:

localhost:8080/add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `post` you should write to the response:

```
self.response.write("Test")
```

In addition; you should not use `print` at all as appengine uses it for internal communication.

Comment: I debugged the program. Everything works OK until the line: return self.redirect("/admin_page"). I added the details in the first post.

Comment: The problem was solved: The value that "result" received was the string "0", not 0 as an int. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return html from your `App.post()` method:

```
self.response.write("<html><body>Test</body></html>")
```

or [redirect](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RedirectHandler) to another page.

Comment: Thanks, but it also happens with redirect. Added the line in the first post.